# How do I write a Kusto query that uses a regex to filter on a where clause

Tags: regex, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

In Azure Log Analytics I'm trying to use Kusto to query requests with a where condition that uses a regex.  The query I'm trying is

```
requests
| where customDimensions.["API Name"] matches regex "\w*-v\d*"
```

but this returns a syntax error.  The example given in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/datatypes-string-operators) is limited but implies that this syntax should work.  A simpler version of the above does work

```
requests
| where customDimensions.["API Name"] matches regex ".*-v.*"
```

What is the correct syntax for `where <predicate> matches regex` in Kusto?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the regex contains backslashes then it must be passed as a verbatim string as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/string).  The following syntax worked

```
requests
| where customDimensions.["API Name"] matches regex @'\w*-v\d*'
```

Comment: How do you invert the matching?

Comment: There's nothing in the `matches regex` operator that would do that so you'd need to use something like a negative lookahead in your regex